# How to send notification to android phone

Tags: android, web-applications, notifications, android-notifications

I'm currently creating an app and a website. And I would like to know how could a website send notification to an android phone ?? Right now what I found is AndroidNotifyMe but are there any other solutions out there ? And for the app, the user have to login with their user id and password.

Thanks in advance. Still a novice programmer!

Comment: maybe look into google cloud messaging?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have a server, you can use `Google Cloud Messaging(GCM)` to push the notification to the android phone. See [here](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).
2. If you don't want to build a server, you can use `Parse.com` for your back-end. See the [doc](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications) and [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bBt8_l60sqM). Also, it can save the `user` and `password` for you.

Answer (score 0):

I typically use MQTT for this kind of applications: reliable, light and very simple to use. You can install the broker in your server, an Android client in the phone and a Javascript client in the website.
You can find all the documentation in [mqtt.org](http://mqtt.org)

Just to give you a hint on the simplicity of the solution:

1) install [mosquitto](http://mosquitto.org) broker into your server and launch it
2) connect to the broker via the ([Eclipse Paho](https://eclipse.org/paho/)) client and subscribe to a topic of your choice

```
MqttClient client = MqttClient(<MQTT_dir>, <MQTT_uri>);
client.connect();
client.subscribe(<topic_name>);
```

3) connect the web page to the broker via Javascript. You can get [instructions](https://github.com/hivemq/hivemq-mqtt-web-client) in GitHub